# WriteableBitmapEx in console application?

Tags: c#, console-application, writeablebitmap, writeablebitmapex

I was wondering if it's possible to use the WriteableBitmap class / the WriteableBitmapEx framework in an ordinary C# console application?
I have tried to add it via nuget and also included a using statement for System.Windows.Media.Imaging, but the type is not being recognized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The System.Windows.Media.Imaging namespace resides in the PresentationCore.dll. In your project explorer, right click on References and pick "Add Reference...", then chose PresentationCore.