# Create WriteableBitmap from resource in console application

Tags: c#, console-application, writeablebitmap, writeablebitmapex

I'm trying to create a WriteableBitmap from an Image on my hard drive using WriteableBitmapEx. I copied the code from the official page after adding the nuget package:

```
WriteableBitmap writeableBmp = new WriteableBitmap(0, 0).FromResource("Data/flower2.png");
```

but I get the error

> 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments

I have added the PresentationCore.dll as I was told here [WriteableBitmapEx in console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297603/writeablebitmapex-in-console-application)
and also a using statement for System.Windows.Media.Imaging.

Comment: The answer to this is exactly what the compiler says. WriteableBitmap does not have a constructor that takes 2 arguments. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.writeablebitmap(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Well I thought that's what the WriteableBitmapEx framework add? This code does work fine in my WinRT App.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *WriteableBitmapEx* library provides a generic factory method for constructing writeable bitmaps, namely `BitmapFactory.New`. Use this portable method instead to generate your dummy writeable bitmap:

```
WriteableBitmap writeableBmp = BitmapFactory.New(0, 0).FromResource("Data/flower2.png");
```

The `BitmapFactory` class is in the `System.Windows.Media.Imaging` namespace (unless you are using the WinRT version of *WriteableBitmapEx*, where it is in the `Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging` namespace).